# pinescript how to make a variable declared in an if statement available globally

Tags: pine-script

in my Pine code I declare a var inside an if statement, when I try to use it outside of the if statement i get an error. How can I make that variable available globally.

Answer (score 1):

Just declare the variable outside of the if block. Then within the if block, you can use the := operator to re-assign a new value to that variable.